# Prune empty and singleton arrayrefs from complex Perl data structure

Tags: perl, data-structures, perl-data-structures, traversal

I'm trying to neaten up a large data structure in Perl which was read in from JSON. Two stereotypical elements look like this (in JSON):

```
[
    [ [ {'payload':'test'} ], [ [ {'payload':'reply'} ], [] ] ],
    [ [ {'payload':'another thread'} ] 
]
```

I want to completely remove that empty arrayref at the bottom of that element, and replace each arrayref containing only a single hashref by the contained hashref. In other words, the result should be this:

```
[
    [ {'payload':'test'}, [ {'payload':'reply'} ] ],
    [ {'payload':'another thread'} ]
]
```

Currently my code is as follows:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS;
use Data::Walk;

sub cleanup {
    if (ref $_ eq 'ARRAY') {
        if (scalar(@{$_}) == 0) {
            die 'mysteriously I never reach this branch!';
            while (my ($key,$value) = each @{$Data::Walk::container}) {
                if ($value == $_) {
                    delete ${$Data::Walk::container}[$key]
                }
            }
        } elsif (scalar(@{$_}) == 1 and ref @{$_}[0]) {
            $_ = @{$_}[0];
        } else {
            my $tail = ${$_}[scalar(@{$_})-1];
            if (ref $tail eq 'ARRAY' and scalar(@{$tail}) == 0) {
                $#{$_}--;
            }
        }
    }
}

sub get {
    my $begin = shift;
    $begin = 0 unless $begin;
    my $end = shift();
    $end = $begin + 25 unless $end;
    my $threads;
    {
        local $/;
        open(my $f, '<emails.json');
        $threads = decode_json <$f>;
        close($f);
    }
    $threads = [ @{$threads}[$begin .. $end] ];
    walkdepth(\&eliminate_singleton, $threads);
    return $threads;
}

print JSON::XS->new->ascii->pretty->encode(&get('subject:joke'));
```

and though it succeeds in removing the empty arrayref, it fails to collapse the singletons. How can this code be corrected such that it can collapse the singletons?

Comment: +1 for a good question. You should call yourself Hedgepruner. ;-)

Comment: It would help enormously if you would post a program that demonstrated the problem. As it stands the code runs a program `notmuch` with a query of `subject:joke` to generate the JSON data. These things are insignicifcant to the problem and unknown to the people that are trying to help you and it takes a significant amount of work to pull apart your code and distinguish the relevant parts from the irrelevant ones. It is good that you have shown some data, but as it stands it is invalid JSON and non-trivial to see how to use it with your program. The result is a very low number of answers.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to remove empty arrays that are elements of arrays, but I don't understand *replace each singleton arrayref by a reference to its element*. Do you perhaps mean to replace each hash value that is a single-element array with its contents?

So

```
[
  "data1",
  [],
  "data3",
]
```

is converted to

```
[
  "data1",
  "data3",
]
```

and

```
{
  "key1" : ["val1", "val2"],
  "key2" : ["val3"],
  "key3" : ["val4", "val5"],
}
```

is converted to

```
{
  "key1" : ["val1", "val2"],
  "key2" : "val3",
  "key3" : ["val4", "val5"],
}
```

In your program the latter corresponds to `"tags" : ["inbox"]` becoming `"tags" : "inbox"`.

If that is the case then this version of `eliminate_singleton` does what you want.

It takes a view from the container node and check whether anything inside needs to be modified. Doing it from the point of view of the node itself can result in nodes being modified while they are being scanned over which will break the program. As it is, looping from the end of an array backwards is safe as it doesn't remove any unvisited nodes.

```
use Scalar::Util 'reftype';

sub eliminate_singleton {

  my $node = $_;
  my $type = reftype $node // '';

  if ($type eq 'ARRAY') {
    for (my $i = $#$node; $i >= 0; $i--) {
      my $subnode = $node->[$i];
      my $subtype = reftype($subnode) // '';
      delete $node->[$i] if $subtype eq 'ARRAY' and @$subnode == 0;
    }
  }
  elsif ($type eq 'HASH') {
    for my $k (keys %$node) {
      my $subnode = $node->{$k};
      my $subtype = reftype($subnode) // '';
      if ($subtype eq 'ARRAY' and @$subnode == 1) {
        $node->{$k} = $node->{$k}[0];
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, not hash elements, array elements. Each message-representation, a hashref, is contained by precisely one extraneous 1-element arrayref.